# Can a base class extension capture and return specific implementation?

Tags: swift, generics

Suppose we have:

```
class BaseClass {
   var id: String
}
class Child1: BaseClass {}
class Child2: BaseClass {}
struct Structure<T : BaseClass> {
    var map = [String: T]()
}
```

Is it possible for an extension to return the specific type?

```
extension BaseClass {
    static func <- <T : BaseClass>(left: T, right: T) -> Structure<T> where T == Self {
        return Structure(map: [left.id, right])
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like T == Self, or the left/right operator being T, but you can see what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to return the specific type of BaseClass so that I only have to implement these operators once.

So then you could use it like this:

```
var child1 = Child1()
var child11 = Child1()
// the structure returned matches the type of the operator inputs
var structure: Structure<Child1> = child1 + child11
```

If I try to put T in the operator left, right params, the compiler doesn't like that either.

This also doesn't work (for obvious reasons), but if there a way I could rewrite it to make it work?

```
extension BaseClass {
    func combine<T : BaseClass>(with: T) -> Structure<T> {
        // this doesn't work because 'self' can be assumed to be T
        return Structure<T>(map: [self.id : with])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the operator. You just can't put it inside of a type.

```swift
func + <T>(left: T, right: T) -> Structure<T> {
  .init(map: [left.id: right])
}

var structure = Child1() + Child1()
```

If you want it to be a method, you'll need a protocol.

```swift
protocol BaseClassProtocol: BaseClass { }

extension BaseClassProtocol {
  func combine(with instance: Self) -> Structure<Self> {
    .init(map: [id: instance])
  }
}

extension BaseClass: BaseClassProtocol { }
```

…but if you're going to have a protocol, you can throw the operator in there too if you want.

```swift
extension BaseClassProtocol {
  static func + (left: Self, right: Self) -> Structure<Self> {
    .init(map: [left.id: right])
  }

  func combine(with instance: Self) -> Structure<Self> {
    self + instance
  }
}
```

Comment: Just explicitly type `structure` then to not be `Structure<BaseClass>`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, In that capture, `func + <T>(left: T, right: T) -> Structure<T>`, does 'left' or 'right's type become T or does it always just choose the closest parent type?

Comment: The two things you said are the same thing!

Comment: If left: Child1 and right: Child2, which type does Structure<T> become?

Comment: It seems as if you're imagining that `Structure<T : BaseClass>` means that T has to derive from `BaseClass`, instead of being able to actually be `BaseClass` itself… 

Comment: Thanks - you've answered most of my question (in terms of taking the operator outside the extension), but could you possibly guide me if its possible to do that `func combine<T : BaseClass>(with: T) -> Structure<T>` example? If you'd be so kind. My question did have 2 sneaky questions.
``

Comment: @JoakimDanielson we could do `func + <T,U>(left: T, right: U) -> Structure<T> where T == U` for my specific question. You could update your answer to that @Jessy

Comment: Sorry. I thought the method was a backup plan! The `T == U` thing won't compile.